# Why Core activity decreased in sklearn after time RFECV/LogisticRegression

Tags: linux, parallel-processing, scikit-learn, jupyter-notebook, cpu-usage

I am using sklearn's feature extraction RFECV, which has a parameter "n_jobs" to allocate core usage.

I have an intel i5-8400 CPU @ 2.80GHz (6 cores)

I am running ubuntu 16.04 (64-bit). latest versions of python, sklearn, etc.

I have 2 jupyter notebooks running simultaneously.  I allocated 5 cores to one and 1 core to another with the n_jobs parameter in RFECV.

here's the code calling for the 5 cores, which isn't working as expected:

```
logreg = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFECV(logreg, step=3, cv=10, n_jobs=5)
rfe = rfe.fit(X_lab, y_lab)
y_pred=rfe.predict(X_lab),
```

Anyway, when I went to sleep, looking at CPU usage with the linux 'top' command, it showed all 6 cores active and nearly at 100% usage (which is what I expected).  However, when I woke up, only 2 are running, as you can see from the first 3 line of the 'top' call on linux:

```
PID USER      PR  NI    VIRT    RES    SHR S  %CPU %MEM     TIME+ COMMAND

10790 ted       20   0 1489568 416948  37064 R 100.0  1.7   2456:08 python3.6                          
781 ted       20   0 1621052 392824  36348 R  99.7  1.6  13:04.46 python3.6                          
937 root      20   0  481136 106528  83944 S   8.0  0.4  42:49.95 Xorg
```

I have a pretty good liquid cooling system in my CPU, plenty of RAM, and I'm not overclocking.  Did I overtax my CPU, or is this possibly something about how the parallelism is implemented on sklearn, or something else entirely? Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

So I think this is just the implementation of sklearn at that point in the algorithm.  The algorithm was done running within about an hour of the last post, and it clearly worked faster than the n_jobs=1 version.  I'm running it again, and it shows all the cores working like it should, so I believe it was 'winding down' so-to-speak and done with the computation-heavy part of the algorithm. . .